# Gazebo model path issue when starting from Java

Tags: java, bash, shell, ros

My team is currently working on a project in Java that involves the robot simulation software Gazebo. To launch Gazebo with a specific world, we have written a shell script that we want to execute with the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` command in Java (or ProcessBuilder).

Here is our problem:

If we start that script from the terminal, everything works perfectly i.e. you can see a world with one of our models (pylons):

[image: start from terminal]

However, if we try to execute that script from within our Java application, it just shows this (models are recognized but not visualized):

[image: start from Java]

We assume that Gazebo doesn't find the gazebo model path although they are defined in `~/.bashrc`.

Has anyone an idea why it is not working. We know that most of you may not know Gazebo, but maybe some of you have dealt with similar issues. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could ensure your script always runs with the proper environment by specifying the specific variables you required in it, or load the environment via `. ~user/.bashrc` at the start of your script.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I switched to the ProcessBuilder and found a way to define an environment variable. It works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for us:

Instead of the "Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)" command, I use the ProcessBuilder.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command(your_command);
builder.directory(new File(your_path));
Map<String, String> env = builder.environment();
env.put("GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH", variable_content);
Process process = builder.start();
```

Now, we can set GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH here and Gazebo loads all worlds correctly